# Is there is UITapGesture size limit between regular and plus sized iPhones

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a UITapGesture to a UILabel in my code.
What is confusing me, when I run the code on an iPhone 7/8 on Hardware or in the Simulator, the TapGesture isn't called.   However if I run the exact same code on an iPhone 7/8 *PLUS* on Hardware or in the Simulator the UITapGesture is fired.

Is there some sort of size limit to touch sizes which is causing this, and how do I get around it?

I have double checked the User Interaction is selected in Xcode.

```
let myTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myAction))
myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(myTap)
```

This is how I am adding the tap.

Comment: The only thing that would cause this is something else in your code interfering with it, or your constraints are causing the label frame to have a width or height of zero (or so small you're missing the tap area), or your constraints are causing another view to interfere.

Comment: More likely there is something wrong with how you are positioning the label within its superview. However, we'd need to see more code.

Comment: Is your label in a scroll view or something that could be in conflict with your gestureRecognizer on smaller screens ? You can implement the gesture delegate to have a better understanding of what is going on

Comment: You can use the view debugger. Click the "Inspect View Hierarchy" button in Xcode, both when running in the simulator and when running on the device. And look for differences. Check that the view hierarchy looks like you expect. Also, put a breakpoint into the `myAction` method to see if it is called. - Another option (maybe) would be to just use a UIButton instead.

Answer (score 0):

DonMag, Matt, and Michael all ended up being part of the winner.

OK basically my views were in a view that were in a segment of a stack view.

Basically the Autolayout was NOT adjusting the superview's height that held all the children views which had the GestureRecognizers.  So even thought the labels were still visible, they weren't receiving the Gestures because they were outside the bounds of the parents.  But was what was weird is this only happened on 7 and 8 and on 7 Plus and 8 Plus.   So basically added a constraint to set the container view's height equal to the stack views height (forcing Autolayout to readjust everything for 7/8 and that seemed to do the trick).

Super annoying, but thanks for the suggestion guys, it was appreciated.

ALso switched to the view storyboards in 7 was a help.